# drawImage() method draws the image small regardless of image size

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I have an `imagepanel` class that draws an image on a JPanel. My problem is that the image appears to be very small inside the `jpanel`, and I dont know why.

I have done all I could and searched the net and even some java books for this little problem but to no success. I really need some help on this one.

I am extremely new to java.

```
    class Weapons extends JPanel {
    private Image weaponimage = weapon1.getImage();

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    if (image != null)
        g.drawImage(weaponimage, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
   }
   }
```

that's the image class.

Comment: If you want help, you have to post some code.

Comment: Is image BufferedImage?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  @mKorbel  Nice tag edits.  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 'instant fix' is to paint that element at its natural size.  E.G. Change this:

```
g.drawImage(weaponimage, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
```

To this:

```
g.drawImage(weaponimage, 0, 0, this);
```

Which seems logical.  A 'weapon' should probably be drawn at natural size.

---

> ..problem is that the image appears to be very small inside the jpanel,

No.  The problem seems to be that the panel itself is very small.  The image is painted the width and height of the panel as assigned by the layout.

To increase the size of the (BG) image, add components to the panel (properly laid out) and display the panel at its preferred size.

Answer (score 1):

May be your class look like this:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

    class Weapons extends JPanel {
        // get image according to your application logic
        BufferedImage image;

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1, 0, 0, image.getWidth() - 1, image.getHeight() - 1, null);
        }

        public void setImage(BufferedImage image){
            this.image = image;
        }
    }

    class Main {
        Weapons weapons;

        public void updateWeapons(){
            // create image
            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
            // draw on image

            // TO UPDATE WEAPONS GUI, below steps are impotant
            weapons.setImage(image);
            weapons.repaint();
        }
    }
```

You have to override paint() method. Then you can set image and call repaint() to update graphics on panel.

Comment: No, you should always avoid overriding paint whee I ever possible, then calling super.paintComponent is going to destroy the entire paint chain, probably causing more problems along the way...

Comment: sir, with regards to this answer, where do i enter the string for the filename of the picture?

Answer (score 0):

use a dimension object to change the size of the image

```
    Weapons picture = new Weapons();
    picture.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110, 160));
    panel.add(picture);
```

do this and you can stretch the length and breadth of your photo as needed.